# C# can an inherited method or property use the derived class members without creating a new method?

Tags: c#

I'm coding a simple game using C# to help me learn basic object oriented concepts.

In this code below:

```
class entity
    {
    int hp;
    string name;

    public entity()
    {
        hp = 1;
        name = "entity";
    }

    public string status()
    {
        string result;
        result=name + "#" + " HP:" + hp;
        return result;
    }






    class dragon : entity
    {

    new public string name;
    new int hp;


    public dragon()
    {
        hp = 100;
        name = "Dragon";

    }
}
```

I made an object for "Dragon" as such

```
dragon mydragon = new dragon();
```

The problem is with the following code:

```
mydragon.status();
```

This returns a string but with the "name" and "hp" of the **entity** class object (i.e. hp=1, name=entity).

I'd like to have this return the dragon object's values (hp=100, name=dragon). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but it seems dead simple.

After fiddling and struggling for hours, the only solution I could come to was to simply copy & paste the **status()** method over to the dragon class. But I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Simply decorate fields `hp` and `name` in the class `entity` with `protected` access modifier. With that, they will be available to the `dragon` class as well and you won't have to redefine them. You can keep the `dragon`'s constructor as it is, since it will run after the constructor in `entity` class, thus overriding values of its fields.

It could look like the following:

```
public class Entity
{
    protected int hp;
    protected string name;

    public Entity()
    {
        hp = 1;
        name = "entity";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string result = name + "#" + " HP:" + hp;
        return result;
    }
}

public class Dragon : Entity
{
    public Dragon()
    {
        hp = 100;
        name = "Dragon";
    }
}
```

It is customary for names of classes in C# to begin with uppercase letter. Also, for stuff like returning string representation of a class, the `ToString()` method is usually overriden.

Comment: Amazing reply! I'm really greatful for this + your tips of the "etiquette" of naming classes :) I'm pretty sure this'll be handy for anyone starting in C# like myself. Never knew the whole trick was to do with the Protected access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add `virtual` keyword in `entity` class to the `status` method and `override` in each inherited class.

edit: Nikola's code looks also very fair if you want to use just `.ToString()` instead of `Status()`

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes...

```
class entity
    {
    protected int hp;
    protected string name;
...


class dragon : entity
    {

    // new public string name;  - you're creating new variables hiding the base ones
    // new int hp;              - ditto. Don't need them
....
```

Comment: Perfect! This exactly fixes the problem right where it is. Very greatful for your reply :)